# combinatorics problem about counting

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Suppose a $n$-sided regular that labeled every vertex from $1$ to $n$.

We know can draw $\frac {(n)(n-3)}{2}$ diameter in $n$-sided regular.

We also know if we want to draw the diameters that none of them cross together we have $n-3$ diameters utmost.

for example for $6$-sided regular we can draw $3$ diameters and it's possible in $14$ ways.

We show this $14$ ways on below picture.

[image]

Now,Suppose we want to count number of diameters that have **$2$** below conditions:

***1-*** none of vertexes don't connect with next $ \ 2\ $ vertexes and before$\ 2\ $ vertexes.(for example vertex number $4$ should not be connected with theses vertexes $ \{5,6,2,3 \} $ in $7$-sided regular.)

***2-*** every $3 \ $ vertexes don't cross together inside the the $n$-sided regular.

My attempt:

I try and count the number of diameters and it is : $2(n-5)$  utmost.

But how can I get The number of draw these $2(n-5)$ in $n$-sided regular?

Comment: **Hint:**  Look up for Catalan numbers.

Comment: @Batominovski Thx alot about your hint but how can i modeling this question with Catalan numbers ? can you explain more for me please?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for http://www.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Classes/Catalan.pdf ?

Comment: THX a lot @EhsanM.Kermani